# How to solve homogeneous linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers, faq

Consider a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ defined by $k$ initial values $(a_1,\dots,a_k)$ and

$$a_{n+k}=c_{k-1}a_{n+k-1}+\dots+c_0a_n$$

for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

What are some ways to get closed forms for $a_n$? What are some ways of rewriting $a_n$ that allows it to be computed without going through all previous values?

For example, we have [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Binet's_formula):

$$F_n=\frac{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}{\sqrt5}$$

Furthermore, what about simultaneously defined linear recurrences? For example:

$$\begin{cases}a_{n+1}=2a_n+b_n\\b_{n+1}=a_n+2b_n\end{cases}$$

How can these be solved?

See also: [Wikipedia: Recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).

---

This is being repurposed in an effort to cut down on duplicates; see here:

- [Coping with abstract duplicate questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756/coping-with-abstract-duplicate-questions)
- [List of abstract duplicates](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions)

Comment: one approach involves matrices

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand. Are you trying to get a standard "homogeneous recurrence relation with constant coefficients" question and accepted/upvoted answer, so that we can all use it to mark the endless particular questions as duplicates?

Comment: @almagest That is the purpose of faq's. See the links at the end. I did a decent search and could not find such a question, but a lot of specific cases in ([tag:recurrence-relations])'s frequent tab, so decided to make this.

Comment: I would remove the ill defined "If a closed form cannot be explicitly achieved", for being false for a moderate definition of "closed form" and for the question that follows being useful regardless of its truth value.

Comment: You can use generating functions.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I am running out of steam. What else do you want me to cover?

Comment: I would find it more readable to index as $$a_{n+k}=c_{k-1}a_{n+k-1}+c_{k-2}a_{n+k-2}+\dots+c_0a_n.$$

Comment: @almagest There's no reason you have to cover every possible answer on your own. The goal is that we get a bunch of useful answers that can be used for these types of problems.See the ([tag:faq]) questions for other such examples.

Comment: The initial values do not need to also be the values in the recurrence formula. There are several obvious answers to this. $1)$ Solve the auxillary polynomial and express $a_n$ as a linear combination of exponentials of the roots. $2)$ Matrix methods. $3)$ Combinatorial interpretations ... I am not sure what you are angling for with this question, shall I go & read the links about duplications ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit You are free to post answers concerning such solutions...

Answer (score 3):

## Characteristic/Auxiliary Polynomials

**The basic solution**

1. Suppose that $\alpha$ is a root of the associated polynomial $$x^k=c_{k-1}x^{k-1}+c_{k-2}x^{k-2}+\dots+c_0\quad(1)$$ Then it is also true that $$\alpha^{n+k}=c_1\alpha^{n+k-1}+\dots+c_0\alpha^n$$ So $a_n=\alpha^n$ satisfies the recurrence relation (but probably not the initial conditions).
2. Since the relation is linear, if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_k$ are the roots of the associated polynomial, then $$a_n=A_1\alpha_1^n+\dots+A_k\alpha_k^n$$ also satisfies the recurrence relation. Provided all $k$ roots are distinct, we can then use the $k$ initial conditions to solve for $A_1,\dots,A_k$.
3. Suppose that $\alpha$ is a repeated root. Then $\alpha$ is also a root of the derivative and so we have $$kx^{k-1}=c_{k-1}(k-1)x^{k-2}+\dots+c_0\quad(2)$$ Taking $nx^n(1)+x^{n+1}(2)$ we get $$(n+k)x^{n+k}=c_{k-1}(n+k-1)x^{n+k-1}+\dots+c_0nx^n$$ and so $a_n=n\alpha^n$ is satisfies the recurrence relation.
4. Similarly, we find that if $\alpha$ is a root of order $h$ (so that $(x-\alpha)^h$ divides the polynomial, then $a_n=\alpha^n,n\alpha^n,n^2\alpha^n,\dots,n^{h-1}\alpha^n$ all satisfy the recurrence relation.
5. So in all cases the associated polynomial gives us $k$ solutions to the recurrence relation. We then take a suitable linear combination of those solutions to satisfy the initial conditions.

**Additional points**

6. If often happens that all but one of the roots $\alpha$ of the polynomial satisfy $|\alpha|<1$ which means that their contribution to $a_n$ is negligible except possibly for small $n$. Since the $a_n$ are usually integers, this means we can often express the solution as $\lfloor A\alpha^n\rfloor$ or $\lceil A\alpha^n\rceil$ (where $\alpha$ is the root with $|\alpha|>1$.
7. We sometimes get simultaneous linear recurrences like the two in the question $$a_{n+1}=2a_n+b_n,b_{n+1}=a_n+2b_n$$ In this case we can eliminate all but one of the sequences, in a similar way to solving ordinary simultaneous equations. In this case we have $b_n=a_{n+1}-2a_n$. Substituting in the other relation; $a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1}=a_n+2a_{n+1}-4a_n$

Comment: I think $c_0$ in $(2)$ is redundant if you got $(2)$ by differentiating $(1)$ where it was a free coefficient.

Answer (score 2):

## Matrices

Such recurrences can be computed using matrices. Let $\mathbf a_n=(a_{n+k-1},\dots,a_n)^\intercal$. We can then easily see that the recurrence relation can be rewritten as

$$\mathbf a_{n+1}=C\mathbf a_n\text{ where }C=\begin{bmatrix}c_{k-1}&c_{k-2}&\cdots&c_1&c_0\\1&0&\cdots&0&0\\0&1&\cdots&0&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&0&\cdots&1&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf c\\\mathbf e_0\\\mathbf e_1\\\vdots\\\mathbf e_{k-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\mathbf e_i$ has a $1$ at the $i$th entry and $0$ everywhere else. See also: [Companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Intuitively we're computing the next term (top row), and then setting each entry as the one above it (a rotation of the values in $\mathbf a_n$ per se).

From this we can easily solve the recurrence, as it now becomes:

$$\mathbf a_n=C^n\mathbf a_0$$

and so the problem reduces to raising $C$ to a power. As it is the case that $C$ is diagonalizable, with eigenvalues given by the roots of the [characteristic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial), a closed form can then be found. Even if the roots are not nice to compute, or if one wishes to avoid non-integers for an integer sequence, this can still be computed using [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

This also easily generalizes to simultaneously defined sequences. Consider the example:

$$\begin{cases}a_{n+1}=2a_n+b_n\\b_{n+1}=a_n+2b_n\end{cases}$$

Let $\mathbf w_n=(a_n,b_n)^\intercal$. We can then rewrite this as

$$\mathbf w_{n+1}=C\mathbf w_n\text{ where }C=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$$

and hence

$$\mathbf w_n=C^n\mathbf w_0$$

To show how this gives an explicit solution, we may diagonalize $C$ as

$$C=VDV^{-1}\\\text{where }D=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&3\end{bmatrix},~V=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix},~V^{-1}=\frac12V$$

and hence

$$\mathbf w_n=V\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&3^n\end{bmatrix}V^{-1}\mathbf w_0=\frac12\begin{bmatrix}(a_0+b_0)3^n+(a_0-b_0)\\(a_0+b_0)3^n-(a_0-b_0)\end{bmatrix}$$

which strongly suggests this specific problem can be solved by observing the behavior of $V^{-1}\mathbf w_n$ i.e. $a_n-b_n$ and $a_n+b_n$.

Answer (score 2):

## Generating functions / Z-transforms

[Generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) ([unilateral Z-transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform)) can be used to transform the recurrence into a formal power series by defining:

$$G=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$

We can then rearrange this to get

$$G=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}a_nx^n+G\sum_{n=1}^kc_{k-n}x^{n-1}$$

Solving for $G$ then gives a rational function in $x$. By factoring the denominator (which equates to solving the characteristic equation), applying partial fractions, and using the geometric series or [Newton's generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem), the general term in the expansion of $G$ can be computed. Alternatively, by using Taylor's series, we know that

$$a_n=\frac{G^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$$

which can be computed directly by differentiating repeatedly, using [Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) for example.

Example:

The Fibonacci sequence can be solved this way. Recall that $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, and $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$. Now let us take

$$G=\sum_{n=0}^\infty F_nx^n$$

By algebraic manipulation,

$$G=x+(x+x^2)G$$

$$G=\frac x{1-x-x^2}$$

For multiple simultaneously defined sequences, this simply amounts to multiple generating functions, which when solving amounts interestingly to solving a system of equations of functions. After that the rest is the same as above.